# displaying json data of multi dimensional array in html table fetched from api

Tags: javascript, json, api

I will be grateful if anyone help me.

I need some help in displaying json data in HTML table format.
json data from API is like that-

```
Object { prices: (471) […], market_caps: (471) […], total_volumes: (471) […] }
​
market_caps: Array(471) [ (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], … ]
​​
[0…99]
​​​
0: Array [ 1619665331929, 0 ]
​​​​
0: 1619665331929
​​​​
1: 0
​​​​
length: 2
​​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​​
1: Array [ 1619668852017, 0 ]
​​​
2: Array [ 1619672451594, 0 ]
​​​
3: Array [ 1619676320179, 0 ]
​​​
```

I am facing real issue with js in extracting json data as I am not able to get data.I have tried many ways including nested loop to get but it not working.
my JS code-

```
// api url
const api_url =
"https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/comfytoken/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=30&interval=minutely";

// Defining async function
async function getapi(url) {
    
    // Storing response
    const response = await fetch(url);
    
    // Storing data in form of JSON
    var data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    if (response) {
        hideloader();
    }
    show(data);
}
// Calling that async function
getapi(api_url);

// Function to hide the loader
function hideloader() {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
}
// Function to define innerHTML for HTML table
function show(data) {
    let tab =
        `<tr>
        <th>Prices</th>
        <th>Marketcap</th>
        <th>Volume</th>
        </tr>`;
    
    // Loop to access all rows
    for (let r of data.list) {
        tab += `<tr>
    <td>${r.prices} </td>
    <td>${r.market_caps}</td>
    <td>${r.total_volumes}</td>
    
</tr>`;
    }
    // Setting innerHTML as tab variable
    document.getElementById("employees").innerHTML = tab;
}
```

my HTML code-

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <!-- Here a loader is created which
            loads till response comes                           <p id="employees"></p>            -->
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="spinner-border"
                role="status" id="loading">
                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1>Chart</h1>
        <!-- table for showing data -->
        <table id="employees"></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

thanks for reading it

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you expect this to look like in the end? Also please provide a smaller sample set of data.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG for responding. You use this api URL for smaller dataset- https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/comfytoken/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=1&interval=hourly                                                                                                    I want to display it like simple table of price, market cap and volume.

Answer (score 0):

The data provided allows for key mapping between the arrays. In this case, we can convert the various arrays into a single array of objects and map those into rows.  I include an example of how that could be done below.

Please refer to the documentation for some of the array methods:

- [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
const loadData = async() => ({
  "prices": [
    [1621359090214, 6.544815910245511e-06],
    [1621362710632, 6.617157866650854e-06],
    [1621366266933, 6.511845773866363e-06],
    [1621369972751, 6.45506329074821e-06],
    [1621373586805, 6.4895192349164596e-06],
    [1621377197778, 6.528440047870483e-06],
    [1621380733154, 6.553322251996456e-06],
    [1621384368464, 6.460241920722578e-06],
    [1621387852771, 6.4966649899102326e-06],
    [1621395190078, 6.203860393053995e-06],
    [1621398752203, 5.8293676073562845e-06],
    [1621402359948, 5.800274968205944e-06],
    [1621405937594, 5.618324509050109e-06],
    [1621409595717, 5.59324926455179e-06],
    [1621413128277, 5.686476265244116e-06],
    [1621416596495, 5.756274919281165e-06],
    [1621420392396, 5.713044744049376e-06],
    [1621424004911, 5.502782733313466e-06],
    [1621427947904, 5.442429292652396e-06],
    [1621431549713, 4.434344021605351e-06],
    [1621434927948, 4.509122624261053e-06],
    [1621434467000, 4.509122624261053e-06]
  ],
  "market_caps": [
    [1621359090214, 0.0],
    [1621362710632, 0.0],
    [1621366266933, 0.0],
    [1621369972751, 0.0],
    [1621373586805, 0.0],
    [1621377197778, 0.0],
    [1621380733154, 0.0],
    [1621384368464, 0.0],
    [1621387852771, 0.0],
    [1621395190078, 0.0],
    [1621398752203, 0.0],
    [1621402359948, 0.0],
    [1621405937594, 0.0],
    [1621409595717, 0.0],
    [1621413128277, 0.0],
    [1621416596495, 0.0],
    [1621420392396, 0.0],
    [1621424004911, 0.0],
    [1621427947904, 0.0],
    [1621431549713, 0.0],
    [1621434927948, 0.0],
    [1621434467000, 0.0]
  ],
  "total_volumes": [
    [1621359090214, 12188.804162995595],
    [1621362710632, 16422.906137378064],
    [1621366266933, 17370.531395103244],
    [1621369972751, 16355.141226289688],
    [1621373586805, 16546.42959627594],
    [1621377197778, 18786.92656973702],
    [1621380733154, 19330.83561775617],
    [1621384368464, 21018.755033279227],
    [1621387852771, 20846.165976772616],
    [1621395190078, 26639.79486946861],
    [1621398752203, 24999.32820385281],
    [1621402359948, 24874.563995550383],
    [1621405937594, 23392.66541329663],
    [1621409595717, 23288.2611903364],
    [1621413128277, 17850.766220657362],
    [1621416596495, 19226.87678704703],
    [1621420392396, 19082.481103324568],
    [1621424004911, 18380.172434939956],
    [1621427947904, 18178.58231224136],
    [1621431549713, 17454.16909223272],
    [1621434927948, 15601.266143252773],
    [1621434467000, 15601.266143252773]
  ]
});

const transformData = (data) => {
  const convertToObj = (arr) => (
    arr.reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
      obj[key] = value;
      return obj;
    }, {})
  );
  const priceObj = convertToObj(data.prices);
  const marketCapsObj = convertToObj(data.market_caps);
  const totalVolumesObj = convertToObj(data.total_volumes);
  return Object.keys(priceObj).map(key => ({
    price: priceObj[key],
    marketCap: marketCapsObj[key],
    totalVolume: totalVolumesObj[key]
  }));
};

(async() => {
  const data = await loadData();
  const dataRows = transformData(data);

  document.querySelector('#loading').style.display = 'none';

  const table = document.querySelector('#employees');
  const header = '<thead><tr><th>Prices</th><th>Market Cap</th><th>Volume</th</td></thead>';
  const tableRows = dataRows.map(row => `<tr><td>${row.price}</td><td>${row.marketCap}</td><td>${row.totalVolume}</td></tr>`).join('\n');
  table.innerHTML = `${header}\n<tbody>${tableRows}</tbody>`;
})();
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id="loading">
    <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
      <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>Chart</h1>
  <!-- table for showing data -->
  <table id="employees"></table>
</body>

</html>
```